# how to fix 'struct.error: char format requires a bytes object of length 1'

Tags: python-3.6, pyvisa

I am trying to use a pyvisa library to write a configuration to a test device.  When I am trying to send the command over I get the following error from the utilty function used to talk with the equipment.

"struct.error: char format requires a byte object of length 1"

I have traced down to the code that is throwing the error and am able to reproduce just the error using a small code fragment which I have included below.

```
iter = b'<setup pro'
fullfmt = '<10c'
header = b'#510'
result = header + struct.pack(fullfmt, *iter)
```

When I do this I expect to get a packed byte structure containing

> b'#510<10c

but instead I get the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
>      exec(code, self.locals)
>    File "", line 1, in 
>   struct.error: char format requires a bytes object of length 1

So them I decided that I would that maybe my format was wrong and that it it should be a 's' instead of a 'c' so I tried the above code again by changing fullfmt from '<10c' to '<10s' and then get the following error message.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
>      exec(code, self.locals)
>    File "", line 1, in 
>   struct.error: pack expected 1 items for packing (got 10)

I'm at a bit of a loss.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok so I made a change to use result = header + struct.pack(fullfmt, iter) and I got the result I'm looking for.  What I don't understand is why the pack using the 'c' format didn't just unroll using the *iter argument?  Can anyone explain why that might be?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Instead of patching `pyvisa/util.py`, I patched my application code by specifying `datatype="B"` instead of `"c"` in the following invocation. `INFINIIUM.write_binary_values(command, values, datatype="B")`

I got the clue from https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/struct.html which said multiple unsigned char has format B.